# How to open and edit JAR bundle in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to direct the Root Context to the Developer Portal in WSO2 APIM tool, i followed this docs:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/customizations/directing-the-root-context-to-the-developer-portal/

but i have no idea how i can open this file

```
org.wso2.am.styles_3.2.0.jar
```

and edit the `component.xml`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps :

1. Right click on the JAR file.
2. Click `Open with other Application`.
3. Select the Archive manager according to your OS.
4. Open the `component.xml` file that is inside `META-INF` directory using a text editor.
5. Edit that text file and Save
6. Restart the server

Comment: Thanks for your help, shall i keep it un compressed or i need to archive it back to .jar ?

Comment: If you un compressed it, You need to archive back to the JAR

Comment: is there a way edit it without un compress it ? like open it directly using Archive manager and edit then save? i am on MacOS

Comment: Thanks i found it by using `vim org.wso2.am.styles_3.2.0.jar` and edit then save, and it worked.